# Pegar um valor que está dentro de um <span> em outro site usando PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar um valor que está dentro de um  de uma URL externa para usar em um determinado cálculo.

Exemplo:
http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm
Quero pegar apenas o valor referente a Soja s/Royalts, que está dentro deste span:
56,50

Comment: Talvez dê certo com uma biblioteca para fazer *parse* de XML...

Comment: Você que desenvolveu o código de onde você quer retirar os valores? Caso tenha sido você, e os dois arquivos estejam no mesmo projeto, você poderia guardar o valor que necessita na seção e recupera-lo adiante.

Comment: Não fui eu que desenvolvi, mas a solução do @user2479421 funcionou bem. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso a tag que você quer pegar não tem id nem nada que a identifique, então só é possível pegar o valor pelo index dela:

```
<?php

// Desabilita erros da libxml e permite que o usuário obtenha informação do erro como necessitar 
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm');

$spans = array();
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span)
{ 
    $spans[] = $span;
}

echo $spans[4]->nodeValue;

?>
```

Comment: Boa solução, a DOM é bastante verbosa pra uma tarefa simples, mas é bem eficaz. No entanto sugiro que jamais se use o arroba para suprimir erros. Imagine que esse HTML porventura não possa ser carregado pela DOM. O arroba vai forçar um FALSE e a Aplicação que dependa dessa informação não saberá o porquê de não estar funcionando e você não terá como debugar pois não terá recebido um **I/O warning**. Muito melhor, nesse caso, é antes de fazer o *load* do HTML, chamar `libxml_use_internal_errors( TRUE );`

Comment: Esta solução funcionou bem. Vou seguir a orientação do @BrunoAugusto também para não suprimir o erro. Obrigada!

Comment: perfeito @BrunoAugusto, já editei o código conforme sua sugestão

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um Client PHP que faça o processamento `DOM` do documento que está nesta URI.

Um componente que pode te ajudar é o [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte):

```
<?php

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client;
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm');
$crawler->filter('span')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```

Comment: Não vou nem falar nada sobre o criador do Goutte, mas o inconveniente dessa abordagem é a necessidade de um segundo componente, o Guzzle.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Eu já usei o Goute em uns 3 projetos. Faz uns 2 anos que não uso, então acredito que devam existir componentes melhores. Se não for necessário interação na página, o uso do ``DOMDocument`` está OK

Comment: Só pra constar nos autos que não foi uma crítica, haja vista o Fabio Potencier ser um nome de grande peso na comunidade. :D

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Roger!

Comment: @BrunoAugusto a própria proposta do Goutte é ser um wrapper entre alguns componentes do Symfony e o Guzzle, com o intuito de facilitar o uso: https://github.com/fabpot/goutte#technical-information. Se não quer utilizar o mesmo, basta implementar algo em cima do Guzzle.

Comment: Mas eu não disse isso :´(