# Buscar tags de imagem dentro de string PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma string do tipo:

```
 Veja o logotipo do PHP: <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Webysther_20160423_-_Elephpant.svg/2000px-Webysther_20160423_-_Elephpant.svg.png">
```

Preciso pegar o caminho da imagem na string. A string pode te várias imagens.

Como posso pegar exatamente o caminho das imagens e remover o restante da string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer algo similar a essa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string_com_img);
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

$srcs = [];

foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
    $srcs[] = $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Essa pergunta também é bem similar ao seu problema. Vale a pena dar uma olhada:

[Pegar um valor que está dentro de um <span> em outro site usando PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26041/pegar-um-valor-que-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-um-span-em-outro-site-usando-php/26048#26048)

Comment: Muito obrigada é justamente o que eu preciso! Logo que puder aceito sua resposta